# What EXACTLY do I do to get my resting heart rate down to below 40?

Tags: running, long-distance-running, heart-rate, sprinting

I tried sprinting for a month and it didn't budge. Now I'm doing long-distance running, but I absolutely hate it. I just want to get my heart rate down to an athletic level as quickly as possible so I can focus on other, funner things/maintain it with other, funner things (like getting muscular, strong, and powerful).

How do I get it down to below 40? How fast does it take to get your heart rate down at all? Also, is a high resting heart rate part of the reason why you get tired quickly?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because heart rate is entirely individual. It may not be possible for you to get your RHR below 40, which is an elite athlete type of level.

Comment: Usually there are two parts - genetics, and environment. With first you can't fight- yet. Second has greater influence in young age. So if that is teenager question - long running can help. For adults that influence is highly limited.